# How to get location from logititude and lattitude in python?

Tags: python, gps, location

i want to show the location by using longitude and latitude in python and after to display it on map. any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
def getLocation():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % "1,1")
    options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
    timeout = 20
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get("https://mycurrentlocation.net/")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    longitude = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="longitude"]')
    longitude = [x.text for x in longitude]
    longitude = str(longitude[0])
    latitude = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="latitude"]')
    latitude = [x.text for x in latitude]
    latitude = str(latitude[0])
    alatitude = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="altitude"]')
    alatitude = [x.text for x in alatitude]
    alatitude = str(alatitude[0])
    return (latitude,longitude,alatitude)
```

what it does is it open a site wait and then get the coords by id name

Comment: look i have latitude=31.562166666666666 and longitude= 74.3284033333334 i want to display map using python from these observations.